# EF Core 2.1 seeding data primary key

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.1

I have just run into an issue, reminiscent of chicken and egg situation.

I'm trying to seed data in EF 2.1.3. I have a class called "Sample".

```
public class Sample
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    }
```

I have the following seed method:

```
builder.HasData(
                new Sample {Id=1, IsActive = true, IsVisible = true, Name = "Test 1" },
                new Sample { Id = 2, IsActive = true, IsVisible = true, Name = "Test 2" },
                new Sample { Id = 3, IsActive = true, IsVisible = true, Name = "Test 3" }
                );
```

Now, this seems to have worked ok the first time I have generated the migrations

Now, however, every time I run Add-Migration command I get this error:

```
The seed entity for entity type 'Sample' cannot be added because another seed entity with the same key value for {'Id'} has already been added. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

Getting rid of Id values from seed data - results in this error:

```
The seed entity for entity type 'Sample' cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property 'Id'.
```

Comment: Never mind - just figured out. I have posted a rather simplistic example. In my case my entity actually inherits from a base class. I have added a mapping for the base abstract class - and EF switched over to table per hierarchy from table per concrete type. The error messages we just a side artifact of that. I have commented out all of the seed data statements - and the resulting mapping told a story, hence the duplicate primary key error (if all of the records are stored in one table - makes sense that you can not have duplicate Ids...)

Comment: Note to self for the future - always post the full story.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Ids has been previously added. You are inserting duplicate key values.

Comment: Indeed I had duplicate `Id` from my end when I was seeding the data. Thank you good sir.

Answer (score 0):

EF core requires keys to be added to the pocos because it needs to know which is the primary key.  You can try adding data attributes  like your `[Key]` and `[Required]` to your class properties

Here is a write up  on [data attributes](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-net-core-data-annotation/)

You also don’t typically have to add ID if your table is auto incrementing  assuming your using a relational database

Comment: From my understanding Properties Id and ClassnameId are automatically inferred as keys and require no further decoration. Furthermore - the database schema has been generated correctly with PKs and autoincrement values set on the Id columns.

Comment: Are you taking a code first approach or a database first approach ?

Comment: Code first. Figured it out - comments above. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but for a different reason:

I had two lists in my seeding code. list1 did work initializing the entries, and  I copied the entries to list2 via list2.AddRange(list1);. Which I did the .HasData call with.

The model building didn't like that, and gave me the "because another seed entity with the same key value for {'Id'}" error.